# Symfony 2 deleting entity with a oneToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony

In my `Gecko.php` i have the following part:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Weight", mappedBy="geckoId")
    */
    private $weights;
```

And in my `Weight.php` i have this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gecko", inversedBy="weights")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gecko_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $geckoId;
```

My gecko delete action is as follows:

```
/**
 * Deletes a Gecko entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{name}", name="gecko_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $name)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($name);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->findOneByName($name);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Gecko entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('gecko'));
}
```

When i click the delete button in my form, i get this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM Gecko WHERE id = ?'
>   with params [5]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`breedr`.`weight`, CONSTRAINT `FK_615077FC45D556` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`gecko_id`) REFERENCES `Gecko` (`id`))

I don't know how to fix this issue. When there are no weights in the database for a specific gecko, they delete fine, but if there are any weights, it won't delete. Ideally i would like to be able to delete all weight data at the same time that a gecko is deleted

Thanks in advance

Andy

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote this, there's nothing wrong with the question?

Comment: Is there a reason for using *gecko* in the title? Gecko is Firefox-s engi,e maybe it confused someone. You can improve the title by replacing *gecko* with *entity*.

Comment: That's a fair point, only mentioned it as it's my situation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Weight", mappedBy="geckoId", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $weights;
```

Add cascade operations to weights, so whenever Gecko will be updated or deleted, the weights related to it will also be updated / removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't manually remove the owned entities of a parent entity before deleting it, you'll get errors like this. You can either loop through all the owned entities and delete them manually before deleting the parent, or you can set Doctrine to automatically cascade delete operations:

[Doctrine Cascade Operations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)